# GRUB boot loader(Ubuntu) not working

Tags: boot, bootloader, ubuntu-14.04

I have a system with ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64 installed. It has stopped booting up after updating. As I power on it, screen glows for 1 sec and it shuts down. While booting as I power on nothing happens, screen just glows for a second and goes off.Most of time as I power on, the wifi symbol gets on and laptop shuts down.The screen doesn't glow in this at all. I downloaded the Ubuntu from net and installed with the help of bootable USB on laptop.It's been 2 days and I have a lot of data in the laptop.

Any Solutions/Suggestions ? Thanks In advance.

Comment: Seems like more of a hardware failure....

Comment: @itachi  i removed HDD and tried starting my laptop. it goes through the POST, and a black screen appears with the message **Operating System Not Found** and remains at this screen.
This means either  HDD is faulty or the OS is corrupt.
Further Any Solutions?